# Is this really how armor works?

Tags: ranged-attack, armor, heroes-unlimited

In Heroes Unlimited, revised second edition, ranged attacks miss on a 7 or below.

Armor increases the minimum Strike result necessary to bypass SDC and affect hit points directly.

Does this mean that, for ranged attacks, having less than 8 armor is meaningless (or that the first 8 points of armor are essentially "wasted")?

I'm building a robot hero and have the ability to use up the last of my budget on increasing my armor but I don't want to spend it on a few points of armor if it won't benefit me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## AR's kind of better than that

At its most basic, Armor Rating (AR) in *Heroes Unlimited, Revised 2nd Edition* (1998) works like this: The minimum roll to strike is 5 or higher, even in ranged combat if the target's within 60 ft. (see page 75). However, if the target of a ranged attack is farther than 60 ft. away, the minimum roll to strike becomes 8 or higher. In all cases, though, to deal damage to the *target* rather than to the target's *armor*, the roll to strike must equal or exceed the target's AR. Thus AR 7 or below is only really wasted if you never fight anyone in close quarters.

That said, let me clarify some other issues:

- If the roll to strike is successful but still below the target's AR, the target's armor is damaged, and the amount of damage is subtracted from the armor's SDC then from the target's natural SDC then from the target's hit points when each, in turn, is exhausted.
- If the roll to strike is successful and equals or exceeds target's AR, the target's natural SDC is damaged, and the amount of damage is subtracted first from SDC then from the target's hit points when that target's natural SDC is exhausted.

As can be seen, hit points are typically behind one or two layers of SDC rather than damaged directly. On the other hand, many exceptions modify this idea and the basic processes above—too many for me to list them all. Nonetheless, most attacks will function this way, likely including those of your robot hero.

### The issue with robot armor

**Other Available Features** (209–10) includes the **Body Armor** feature, which begins by providing standard starting robot SDCs (including those for vehicle-type robots). In that section is a note that says that adding armor increases the robot's "overall" SDC (presumably its "natural" SDC as per the examples above but undefined by the text). That's followed by how much "body armor" (SDC) can be added to each kind of 'bot. On the next page is the **Armor Rating** feature that says that AR starts at 6 and can be increased by 1 for $100,000 up to maximum of 15–17, depending on the 'bot. No further information is present on how this AR works or how or even if these two sections are supposed to work in conjunction. (Seriously. The errata is [here](https://palladiumbooks.com/58-resources/cutting-room-floor/230-heroes-unlimited-2nd-ed-erratta). And those who've read or played this game may find the dearth amusing.)

This means that step one is asking the GM how this works. (You better like the GM. You'll be asking about a lot.) I see at least three options:

- **High-powered Option:** Buy SDC from **Body Armor** and add it to your Standard Robot SDC. Buy your AR from **Armor Rating** and treat it as natural AR (see **Armor Rating or A.R.** on 66–7). You may spend over $1 million on AR, but it's worth every penny. Enjoy nigh-indestructibility.
- **Low-powered Option:** Ignore the note and assume **Body Armor** and **Armor Rating** are one section. You're buying a shell or suit or armor plates or whatever, and attacks below the purchased AR but that still hit damage that newly-bought SDC. You'll still be able to take a lot of punishment, but you will also spend a fortune on repairs.
- **Literalist Option:** Buying **Body Armor** SDC (on page 209) adds to the 'bot's "natural" SDC, but the section **Armor Rating** (on page 210) is ignored because the game never followed up on how it works. (Just cross out that section or something.) Like above, you'll have a lot of SDC and spend a fortune on repairs, but now you've sped play by only having one pile of SDC instead of two. Weirdly, this ends up a mid-range option: there's no chance of a hit striking a weaker section like with the low-powered option, but there's also no chance of ignoring a hit like with the high-powered option.

Honestly, I think there's a campaign for each of these readings, which is why I encourage consulting with the GM. If you can't consult with the GM—you're making a character to experiment with the system, for instance—consider designing the character using one option then again using another option and seeing which feels right to you for the power level of your character.

---

***Note:** To be doubly clear, I'm using the 1998 printing of this game. Palladium Games sometimes updates its games with subsequent printings without commentary, so the information presented here may differ from that of a later printing of this game.*

Comment: I love the different systems 90s TTRPG designers came up with to represent armor's effects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In the case of the robot I'm building, I can't see where it says (I'm looking at page 209 here) "a robot's armor is considered to have natural armor" or something equivalent. Help point me to where that is written?

Comment: @Rykara I wish I could. The game expects the GM to fill in any gaps by making up stuff. Determining RAW in Palladium is often a fool's errand. Suggestion: Although the note says that players can increase their robot's overall SDC with armor, that reads like nonsense in light of the heading Body Armor *and* the presence of a base Armor Rating. Perhaps just ignore the note and buy the stuff under that heading as body armor? (That is, having no body armor means no AR but buying at least 10 SDC of body armor grants a base AR 6 for that newly purchased pile of SDC; then go up from there.)